# cakephp find('list') multiple columns for select box

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Im new to Cake PHP and this forum.

This is my question. I just want to create a select box using cake PHP. Data is coming from database table.

My Customers table looks like this :

```
    id | first_name | last_name
 --------------------------------
    1  |   John     |   Doe
 --------------------------------
    1  |   Sam     |   Doe
```

I just tried to get the data using this method

```
    $this->set('customers', $this->Customer->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('Customer.id', 'Customer.first_name')
    )));
```

View code :

```
      echo $this->Form->input('customers');
```

This create a select box just like this:

```
    <select name="data[Order][customers]" id="OrderCustomers">
    <option value="1">John</option>
    <option value="2">Sam</option>
    </select>
```

My question is how do I display first name & last name in select box just like below.

```
     <option value="1">John Doe</option>
     <option value="2">Sam Doe</option>
```

Much appreciate your answers! Thanks

Comment: So... what have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: I tried to add   like this , But It didnt work :  'fields' => array('Customer.id', 'Customer.first_name','Customer.last_name')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields)

The model would have

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'full_name' => 'CONCAT(Customer.first_name, " ", Customer.last_name)'
);
```

Then you can use it in the `find` call:

```
$this->set('customers', $this->Customer->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Customer.id', 'Customer.full_name')
)));
```